# JSF composite does not store state with StateHelper

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, composite

I am developing a JSF composite that gets a complex data structure as argument:

```
<cc:interface componentType="MyComponent">
    <cc:attribute name="myModel"    required="true"     type="my.package.Model" />
</cc:interface>
```

The backing component processes this model using an init() method that is invoked in the composite via an event:

```
    <cc:implementation>
        <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
        [...]
    </cc:implementation>
```

In this init() method I check if the model has already been processed (because I don't want to do that every time the user stays on the page, e.g. through ajax requests). Hence I store the processed model via StateHelper.put():

```
public void init() 
{
    if (getMyModel() == null)
    {
        MyModel model = processModel(...);
        setMyModel(model);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MyModel getMyModel()
{
    return (MyModel) getStateHelper().get("MyModel");
}

public void setMyModel(MyModel MyModel)
{
    getStateHelper().put("MyModel", MyModel);
}
```

I expect now, that if the init() method is invoked for example during an Ajax request (in the same view scope) it does not process the model a second time because I have stored it in the view scope via the StateHelper. But no matter what I try, if I click on a command link with void/null outcome the getMyModel() method always returns null.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing the `restoreState()` method in the backing component and setting a breakpoint revealed the problem. The `postAddToView` event is processed *before* the invocation of `restoreState()`. Using `preRenderView` instead resolved the issue for me.